# Asterisk red color not displaying in materialspinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

The below code is using string resources to display an asterisk, but the color of the asterisk is displaying black for the below spinner. I want to change the asterisk color to the below mentioned font color. Can any one help me?

String.xml:

```
 <string name="asteriskred"><font color='#cc0029'>*</font></string>
```

Java:

```
spinnertaskType=rootView.findViewById(R.id.task_type);
taskTypes.add("Task Type"+" "+getString(R.string.asteriskred));//asterisk color is displaying black
```

activity.xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                                        android:padding="0dip">

                                        <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                                            android:id="@+id/task_type"
                                            android_id="@+id/task_type"
                                            android_layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android_layout_width="match_parent"
                                            app_ms_arrowColor="#0000FF"
                                            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                                            app_ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                                            app_ms_floatingLabelColor="#00FF00"
                                            app_ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
                                            app_ms_hint="hint"
                                            android:padding="0dip"
                                            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                                            android:theme="@style/ThemeSpinner"
                                            app_ms_multiline="true"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            app:ms_arrowColor="@color/black"
                                            app:ms_hintColor="@color/hint_color" />
                                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: for font tag, I think it has to use like this `Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string. asteriskred))` when u set text

Comment: @HeinHtetAung no it is not working

Comment: try this. 
<string name="asteriskred">
        <![CDATA[
        <font color=\'#cc0029\'>*</font>
        ]]>
    </string>

Comment: Not working ......

Comment: How do u set the adapter? coz fromHtml need to use before you set to textview. Have to set `Spanned` to textview directly.

Comment: No can you give some example

Comment: check this one for custom adapter,

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html

Comment: Inside the getView, when u set text to textview. it should be like this. 
textView.text = Html.fromHtml(textType)